# How to achieve Asynchronous I/O in python2.7?

Tags: python, django

I have my project running in django1.1, how to implement async support for one of the methods which involves call made to db, I want to optimize it.
I have gone through tornado library but I am not sure how to implement / use it with django1.1. Please suggest if there is any other library to achieve async support and how to use tornado with django

Comment: you can look into celery, it will help you with async. Any celery versions in 4.*  will do for python2.7

Comment: Don't be surprised if you get a low response to this question. Python 2 is obsolete, and Python 3 has built-in support for async. Those of us who still write in Python 2 do it because we have to support or migrate legacy code.